# How to manipulate image bands as arrays of numbers

Tags: python, image, matrix, linear-algebra, svd

I'm new to Python, and I'm trying to deconstruct image bands as arrays of numbers by applying the [Singular Value Decomposition (SVD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) to them and then putting them back together with `matplotlib.image` and the `Image` module from `PIL`. An SVD may also be written as a sum of dyads s<sub>1</sub>u<sub>1</sub>v<sub>1</sub><sup>T</sup> + ... + s<sub>K</sub>u<sub>K</sub>v<sub>K</sub><sup>T</sup>, and the point in decomposing it in this way is that a near-perfect approximation of the image can be made from just a few of those dyads, so less data is required.

There must be something wrong with the calculation, though because `result_r`, `result_g`, and `result_b` look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2I9Z.png) when converted to Images, and [`new_image` looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpcDC.jpg).

For an example of what this should look like, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUnfC.jpg) are the first dyads of the layers of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IogpM.jpg) image. The image that I'm using (April23.jpg) is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FxCD.jpg).

```
import matplotlib.image as image
import numpy.linalg as la
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def getcolumn(j, m):
    col = []
    for i in range(len(m)):
        col.append(m[i][j])
    return col

def extractCols(U):
    Ucols = []
    for j in range(len(U[0])):
        Ucols.append(getcolumn(j, U))
    return np.asarray(Ucols)

def vectorMultiply(u, v):
    matrix = []
    for i in range(len(u)):
        newVec = []
        for j in range(len(v)):
            newVec.append(u[i] * v[j])
        matrix.append(newVec)
    return np.asarray(matrix)

im = Image.open('C:/Users/<user>/Desktop/img/April23.jpg')
im.load()

sim = Image.Image.split(im)

rsim = sim[0].save("rsim.jpg") # image bands as images
gsim = sim[1].save("gsim.jpg")
bsim = sim[2].save("bsim.jpg")

# image bands as arrays of numbers
arsim = image.imread('C:/Users/<user>/Desktop/img/rsim.jpg')
agsim = image.imread('C:/Users/<user>/Desktop/img/gsim.jpg')
absim = image.imread('C:/Users/<user>/Desktop/img/bsim.jpg')

ur, sr, vhr = la.svd(arsim, False) # SVD on each band
ug, sg, vhg = la.svd(agsim, False)
ub, sb, vhb = la.svd(absim, False)

urcols = extractCols(ur)
ugcols = extractCols(ug)
ubcols = extractCols(ub)

# calculating the first dyads
result_r = np.multiply(sr[0], vectorMultiply(urcols[0], vhr[0]))
result_g = np.multiply(sg[0], vectorMultiply(ugcols[0], vhg[0]))
result_b = np.multiply(sb[0], vectorMultiply(ubcols[0], vhb[0]))

r = Image.fromarray(result_r, "L")
g = Image.fromarray(result_g, "L")
b = Image.fromarray(result_b, "L")

new_image = Image.merge("RGB", (r, g, b))
```

What am I missing, here? It seems to be something with the calculations. I figured for a matrix one would have to extract the columns, say the column [1, 2, 3] from a matrix [[1,...], [2,...], [3,...]], since each element of the matrix is a row. So, I wrote `extractCols()` for that. `numpy`'s matrix `add` and `multiply` seem to be fine. I wrote `vectorMultiply` because `np.dot()`, `np.multiply()`, and `np.matmul()` didn't seem to realize that `u` was a column and kept saying the dimensions didn't match up. I tested it and it seemed to do what I wanted it to. I was also thinking that maybe the "rows" of `U` are actually the columns already and don't need to be extracted, but that didn't work either. I've also tried not using `np.asarray()` without any luck.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: too much code, please reduce to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Where is `getcolumn`?  Have you looked at your datatypes?  Your JPGs do not have three components, so `arsim`, `agsim`, and `absim` have shape (640,480), not (640,480,3).